# Prove that $\{A\subset Y : A \ \text{is open within} \ Y \} = \{B \cap Y : B \ \text{is open within} \ X\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Exercise**

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subset X$. Prove that

(a) $\{A\subset Y : A \ \text{is open within} \ Y \} = \{B \cap Y : B \ \text{is open within} \ X\},$

(b) $\{F \subset Y : F \ \text{is closed within} \ Y \} = \{G \cap Y : G \ \text{is closed within} \ X\}.$

**My attempt**

(a) Let us prove the inclusion $\subseteq$ first.

If $A$ is open within $Y$, it is open within $X$ because $Y\subset X$. Hence $A = B\cap Y$, where $B = A$.

We may now prove the inclusion $\supseteq$.

Let $A = B\cap Y$ where $B$ is open within $X$. We shall prove that $A$ is open in $Y$ (since it is clear that $A\subset Y$).

This is where I get stuck.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Let $a\in A$. As $B$ is open there exists $r>0$ such that $B_X(a,r) \subseteq B$ and we remark that $B_Y(a,r)=B_X(a,r) \cap Y \subseteq A$.

Comment: If $A$ is open in $Y$, then it is not necessary that it is open in $X$

Comment: For the first inclusion, for all $a\in A$ there exists $r(a)>0$ such that $B_Y(a,r(a)) \subseteq A$ and you should consider $B=\bigcup_{a\in A} B_X(a,r(a))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Some of what follows has been remarked upon in the comments already.

You have made a mistake in assuming that $A$ open in $Y$ $\implies$ $A$ open in $X$. Here is a simple counterexample: Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=Y=[0,\infty)$. Clearly $A$ is open in $Y$, since every metric space is open as a subset of itself. Yet $A$ is not open in $X=\mathbb{R}$, because $0\in A$ and for each $\delta>0$, the interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ contains negative numbers i.e. it not a subset of $A$.

A little nitpicking: '**Hence** $A=B\cap Y$, where $B=A$.' This is true for all $A\subseteq Y$, and does not follow from the previous sentence.

Here is how I would approach this problem:

---

Denote the open ball centred at $x\in X$ of radius $r>0$ in $X$ by $B_r^X(x)$. Similarly for open balls in $Y$ (it is important here to make a clear distinction between open balls in $X$ and in $Y$). Since the subspace metric on $Y$ is defined to be the restriction of the metric on $X$ to $Y$, we have that $B^Y_r(x)=B^X_r(x)\cap Y$.

(a) Let $A\subseteq Y$. If $A$ is open in $Y$, then for each $y\in A$, there exists $\delta_y>0$ such that $B_{\delta_y}^Y(y)\subseteq A$. Define $$B:=\bigcup_{y\in A}B_{\delta_y}^X(y).$$ Since open balls in $X$ are open in $X$, and unions of open sets in $X$ are open in $X$, we have that $B$ is open in $X$. It is then fairly routine to check that $A=B\cap Y$, and we have proved that LHS $\subseteq$ RHS.

Suppose that $A=B\cap Y$ for some $B$ open in $X$. Then for each $y\in A$, we have that $y\in B$ and $B$ is open in $X$, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta^X(y)\subseteq B$ and then $B_{\delta}^Y(y)\subseteq A$, giving that $A$ is open in $Y$, and we are done.

(b) Let $F\subseteq Y$. If $F$ is closed in $Y$, then $Y\setminus F$ is open in $Y$, so by part (a) we have that $Y\setminus F=B\cap Y$ for some $B$ open in $X$. Then $F=Y\setminus(B\cap Y)=(X\setminus B)\cap Y$, where $X\setminus B$ is closed in $X$. This shows that LHS $\subseteq$ RHS.

Finally, if $F=G\cap Y$ for some $G$ closed in $Y$, then $Y\setminus F=(X\setminus G)\cap Y$, where $X\setminus G$ is open in $X$, so part (a) gives that $Y\setminus F$ is open in $Y$ and therefore $F$ is closed in $Y$.

---

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.